# PHP difference between @header() and header() function

Tags: php, header

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

What's the difference between calling @header() and header() function in PHP ?

Comment: `@` [suppresses errors](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php). Don't use that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@` suppresses errors:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

generally, you don't want to do that